# Distinct objects into distinct boxes: two different statements?

Tags: combinatorics

I am having a little doubt in these two statements for the following same problem.: No. of ways of distributing $n$ different objects into k different bins. I was going through *A Walk through Combinatorics* and according to it:

> If we have to put n different balls into k different boxes then the number of ways to do this is $k!S(n,k)$, where $S(n,k)$ is Stirling number of second kind.

The explanation goes like this:-

> first we can partition $[n]$ into $k$ non-distinguishable parts in $S(n, k)$ ways, then we can label the $k$ parts with labels $1,2, \cdots, k$ in $k!$ different ways.

And then this statement

> Suppose there are $n$ distinct objects that are to be distributed among $r$ distinct bins. This can be done in precisely $r^n$ ways.

Please pardon me if the question is stupid, but I am in confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) $S(n, k)$ counts the number of ways of ways of distributing $n$ distinct objects to $k$ indistinguishable boxes when *no box is left empty*.  Therefore, the formula $k!S(n, k)$ counts the number of ways of distributing $n$ distinct objects to $k$ distinct boxes when no box is left empty.

On the other hand, $r^n$ counts the number of ways of placing $n$ distinct objects in $r$ distinct bins without restriction, meaning that some of the boxes may be left empty.

Comment: Thanks that cleared my doubt. But i guess there's typo in second line as Stirling number S(n,k) counts distint object to identical bins??

Comment: @Adrenaleontechie  Yes, you are correct.  Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

"Different to different" statement is equivalent to the number of functions $f:A\to B$ with $|A|=n$ and $|B|=k$. Then it depends if you allow repetitions (of bins in this case) or not and if you allow some element in $B$ to be assigned to no elements in $A$.

In this specific case you look for the total number of functions among those sets, since I guess you are allowed to repeat bins and to left some of them empty: this number is $k^n$.

Why?

Because take every element into the domain, there are $k$ possibilities for it to go to an element of the image. Same things with the others. Of course you need to multiply them together and thus you get the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer..