# Distributing $n$ items among $k$ objects - Both Unique

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

If I had one of each of $n>0$ types of items to distribute to $k>0$ unique objects and I assume $k \leq n$, how many ways are there allocate the items if you put one item with each object?

**My approach:**

Partition the objects by $k-1$ to create k sets of items.  Altogether this would be $(n+k-1)!$ You remove duplicate results by dividing by $n!$ items and also $(k-1)!$ identical objects.  Following that thinking, if items and objects were identical with themsleves then there would be $(n+k-1)!\over(k-1)!n!$ possibilities.

However, in this case both the objects and items are unique.   Therefore, you have to multiply back in $(k-1)!$ and $n!$.   The product of the identical solution and this case would be $(n+k-1)!$  I think this would be the solution but I am not confident in it.  But, I am also thinking that if I am restricted to one item with each object then my solution would not apply.  I am deadlocked here and I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: I believe this is $k!S(n,k)$, where $S(n,k)$ denotes stirling numbers of the second kind.

Comment: If you mean at least one item is placed with each object, then Alan Abraham's answer is correct.  You could also obtain the answer by applying the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle.

Comment: Ok, [before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3808066/distinct-objects-into-distinct-boxes-two-different-statements) @N.F.Taussig .   If I understand, the $k!S(n,k)$ approach is for when you're counting the number of ways of distributing $n$ distinct objects into $k$ distinct boxes when none are left empty.  If boxes were permitted to be  empty, the answer would be $r^n$.   If I have identical containers and distinct items the answer would be $S(n,k)$?  And if I had distinguishable items/containers and I put exactly one item in each container I'd have $S(n,k)$ as well?

Comment: The Stirling number of the second kind $S(n,k)$ counts the number of ways of placing $n$ distinct objects in $k$ indistinguishable boxes when no box is left empty. The number of ways of placing $n$ distinct objects in $k$ distinct boxes when no box is left empty is $k!(n, k)$. The number of ways of placing $n$ distinct objects in $k$ boxes when boxes may be left empty is $k^n$. The number of ways of placing $n$ distinct objects in $k$ distinct boxes when exactly one item is placed in each box is $\binom{k}{n}n! = \frac{k!}{(k - n)!} = P(k, n)$ (here, we get $0$ unless $k > n$).